# Is the behavior of the following C program undefined?

Tags: c

I'm looking in one of my old courses and I find the following:

```
int main(void) {
    int x = 0;
    return (x = 1) + (x = 2);
}
```

"According to C standard, the behavior of the program above is undefined.

GCC4, MSVC: returns 4

GCC3, ICC, Clang: returns 3"

There's a slide after this saying the following code is not undefined in the C standard. Can anyone explain to me why it's not undefined behavior?

```
int main(void) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 2;
    return (x = 4) + (x=(x + y)/2);
}
```

Comment: I will suggest just don't do it.

Comment: The title of your question and the question you ask don't match.

Comment: Also `cout` is C++, so I would probably....not trust that information (which you apparently are not, since you're here asking about it.  Good job!)

Comment: @JasonCHAN "just don't do it." is good advice, yet probing the corners of the language, to understand it  limitations is good.  Worthy of an UV, now the C++ -ish-ness removed.

Comment: "my old courses" --> what course asserted `(x = 4) + (x=(x + y)/2)` is not undefined?

Comment: @chux Semantics of Programming Languages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relevant passages from the C specification:

> Given any two evaluations A and B, if A is sequenced before B, then the execution of A shall precede the execution of B. (Conversely, if A is sequenced before B, then B is sequenced after A.) **If A is not sequenced before or after B, then A and B are unsequenced.**

and

> **If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.** If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.

---

Thus, both snippets in your question invoke undefined behavior.

(Because originally your second snippet was C++, it's worth mentioning that even though recent versions of C++ have expanded the notion of what "sequenced before" and "sequenced after" mean, AFAIK it still doesn't include `operator+` as a sequence point.)